# Select multiple tables and custom column to POCO

Tags: servicestack

I have an export query that returns multiple tables with a lot of columns.

```cs
var q = db.From<Blog>()
        .Join<Blog, UserAuthCustom>((b, u) => b.UserAuthCustomId == u.Id)
        .Join<UserAuthCustom, BloggerProfile>((u, bp) => u.Id == bp.UserAuthCustomId)
        .Join<Blog, BlogToBlogCategory>((b,bc)=> b.Id == bc.BlogId)
        .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>((btbc, bc) => btbc.BlogCategoryId == bc.Id)
        .GroupBy<Blog, UserAuthCustom, BloggerProfile>((b, u, bp) => new { t1 = b.Id, t2 = u.Id, t3 = bp.Id });
        
q.Select<Blog, UserAuthCustom, BloggerProfile>((b,u,bp) => new {
    Blog = b,
    UserAuthCustom = u,
    BloggerProfile = bp,
    BlogCategroiesJson = Sql.Custom($"json_agg({q.Table<BlogCategory>()})")
});
```

This query generates the correct SQL but I am having difficulty getting it into a POCO.

I made this class:

```cs
public class BlogImportExportIntermediate
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public UserAuthCustom UserAuthCustom { get; set; }
    public BloggerProfile BloggerProfile { get; set; }
    private string _blogCategroiesJson { get; set; }

    public string BlogCategroiesJson
    {
        get => _blogCategroiesJson;

        set
        {
            _blogCategroiesJson = value;
            BlogCategories = PostgreSqlMethods.FromJson<List<BlogCategory>>(value);
        }
    }

    public List<BlogCategory> BlogCategories { get; set; }
}
```

But if I try:

```cs
var results = db.Select<BlogImportExportIntermediate>(q);
```

Then it only matches `BlogCategroiesJson`. I guess it has to match column name to property name and doesn't process entire table as property.

I can get everything apart from categories by selecting the tuple:

```cs
var results = db.Select<Tuple<Blog, UserAuthCustom, BloggerProfile>>(q);
```

But how can I fully populate `BlogImportExportIntermediate` in a single query without having to specify every column on every table?

I tried:

```cs
var results = db.Select<Tuple<Blog, UserAuthCustom, BloggerProfile, string>>(q);
```

But this gives object reference error.  I have played around trying to make `BlogCategroiesJson` its own class but can't get it to work.

I am using this query in an export function so getting it all in a single query will be helpful as it could be large result set.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix Table Types with scalar types in the same tuple or multi-select API, you either need to select all Table types or all scalar types.

You can try wrapping the Json column in a POCO Type with the same name as the selected column, e.g:

```
public class BlogCategoryJson
{
    public string BlogCategroiesJson { get; set; }
}

var results = db.Select<Tuple<Blog,UserAuthCustom,BloggerProfile,BlogCategoryJson>>(q);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks!  I had tried that but I didn't add an `[Ignore]` attriblue to the `List<BlogCategory> BlogCategories` property so the column numbers were not matching.